# Debugging jquery / watching JS command as they are called

Tags: jquery, debugging

I am trying to debug an existing app that uses jquery. I'm trying to find where a callback function is set for an onchange, but I cant find it anywhere, possibly due to the JS code being loaded via ajax (not my idea).

Is there a tool I can use, preferably a firefox or chrome plugin, that will let me get a list of JS calls that executed on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get Firebug.](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If stepping through calls manually is enough for you, get the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebug when I'm in an environment (read: at work) that doesn't have access to Chrome.  When I use Chrome, I use those tools, which are quite similar to what Firebug lets you do.

Overall, I find that Chrome = win.

Oh, and in Chrome, your Developer Tools (built in, no plugin needed) and/or Javascript tools do very nicely.  Ctrl+Shift+J for the Javascript tools, IIRC.